# Best way to get multiple newly created key values from table inserts using SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

The function Scope_Identity() will provide the last generated primary key value from a table insert.  Is there any generally accepted way to get multiple keys from an insertion of a set (an insert resulting from a select query)?

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server 2005 onwards, you can use the [OUTPUT clause](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) to get a returned set of values. From the linked article:

> The following example creates the
>   EmployeeSales table and then inserts
>   several rows into it using an INSERT
>   statement with a SELECT statement to
>   retrieve data from source tables. The
>   EmployeeSales table contains an
>   identity column (EmployeeID) and a
>   computed column (ProjectedSales).
>   Because these values are generated by
>   the SQL Server Database Engine during
>   the insert operation, neither of these
>   columns can be defined in @MyTableVar.

```
USE AdventureWorks ;
GO
IF OBJECT_ID ('dbo.EmployeeSales', 'U') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE dbo.EmployeeSales;
GO
CREATE TABLE dbo.EmployeeSales
( EmployeeID   int IDENTITY (1,5)NOT NULL,
  LastName     nvarchar(20) NOT NULL,
  FirstName    nvarchar(20) NOT NULL,
  CurrentSales money NOT NULL,
  ProjectedSales AS CurrentSales * 1.10 
);
GO
DECLARE @MyTableVar table(
  LastName     nvarchar(20) NOT NULL,
  FirstName    nvarchar(20) NOT NULL,
  CurrentSales money NOT NULL
  );

INSERT INTO dbo.EmployeeSales (LastName, FirstName, CurrentSales)
  OUTPUT INSERTED.LastName, 
         INSERTED.FirstName, 
         INSERTED.CurrentSales
  INTO @MyTableVar
    SELECT c.LastName, c.FirstName, sp.SalesYTD
    FROM HumanResources.Employee AS e
        INNER JOIN Sales.SalesPerson AS sp
        ON e.EmployeeID = sp.SalesPersonID 
        INNER JOIN Person.Contact AS c
        ON e.ContactID = c.ContactID
    WHERE e.EmployeeID LIKE '2%'
    ORDER BY c.LastName, c.FirstName;

SELECT LastName, FirstName, CurrentSales
FROM @MyTableVar;
GO
SELECT EmployeeID, LastName, FirstName, CurrentSales, ProjectedSales
FROM dbo.EmployeeSales;
GO
```

Comment: Perfect; didn't know about OUTPUT.

Answer (score 0):

Use the row count and last identity value....

```
DECLARE @LastID  int
DECLARE @Rows    int

--your insert from a select here

SELECT @LastID=@@IDENTITY, @Rows=@@ROWCOUNT

--set of rows you want...
SELECT * FROM YourTable Where TableID>@LastID-@Rows AND TableID<=@LastID
```